# Command to open new terminal window from the current terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I installed xdotool by running `sudo apt-get install xdotool` and throw  `xdotool key ctrl+alt+t` command to open a new terminal window from the current one.But it was not working.

What was the command to open a new terminal window from the current gnome-terminal?

Comment: ctrl + shift + n

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Just this command will do:

```
gnome-terminal
```

Normally if you want a command to open from the terminal and separate *(so it returns to the prompt without having to close the opened program)*,  you have to use something like this:

```
gnome-terminal & disown
```

However the parent terminal seems to detect that the same command is being used so you don't need to do that and `gnome-terminal` will suffice. This also seems to happen when running `xfce4-terminal` from Xfce's terminal, `konsole` from KDE's as well (doesn't seem to work when running `xterm` from `xterm` (see also [`xterm xterm`](https://askubuntu.com/q/488873/178596)) - Running `konsole` from Gnome/Unity & Xfce's terminal works *as well*, but for Xfce's terminal in gnome terminal you need `xfce4-terminal & disown`).

For more visit [`gnome-terminal`'s manual page](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal):

```
 gnome-terminal  [-e,  --command=STRING]   [-x, --execute ]  [--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME]  [--tab-with-profile=PRO‐
       FILENAME]    [--window-with-profile-internal-id=PROFILEID]    [--tab-with-profile-internal-id=PROFILEID]    [--role=ROLE]
       [--show-menubar]   [--hide-menubar]   [--geometry=GEOMETRY]   [--disable-factory]  [-t, --title=TITLE]  [--working-direc‐
       tory=DIRNAME]  [--usage]  [-?, --help]
```

Comment: You probably want to run it in the background, like that: `gnome-terminal &`. Otherwise the current terminal will be unusable, as it will be busy running that other one - so you end up with just one usable terminal, which may be missing the point.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 13.10 install, that did not appear to be a problem @RafałCieślak - I did think about that :-)

Comment: Interesting. You are apparently right, however, I am not wrong neither :) I've just checked that in details. If I run `gnome-terminal` *while* another instance of it is already running (it may be the one I'm using to launch this command) - it indeed finishes immediately, because instead of running a new instance `gnome-terminal`, it tells that currently running one to open a new window. Tricky. But if I run `gnome-terminal` from *anything else*, and there are no other instances of `gnome-terminal` running, it does as I explained in the previous comment, blocking the terminal used to launch it.

Comment: @RafałCieślak - anyway, `konsole` doesn't seem to need at all... weird. I have no idea why this question/answer is so popular :)

Comment: Thanks very much, if you want to open a terminal with the same directory you could do this,
`gnome-terminal .`

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu MATE (e.g. 16.x) it's `mate-terminal`

Comment: And for Unity (since ubuntu 17.10)?

Comment: @JHBonarius (having not used a desktop version) doesn't it now come with Gnome by default, so it should be the same (or is there something else? Unity used to use gnome-terminal (and other Gnome apps like Nautilus), though they used to be modified in more recent versions.

Comment: lubuntu 18.04. gnome-terminal and xfce-terminal seem to work except the colors are a bit off.

Answer (score 11):

Command to open new terminal window from the current terminal,

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+n
```

To install `xdotool`,

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T will open a new terminal tab.

Comment: It is a new terminal... but in a new tab rather than new window.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `xdotool key ctrl+shift+n` while using `gnome-terminal` you have many other options; see `man gnome-terminal` in this sense.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+N will open a new terminal window.

Comment: Still think this neat :) is there any equivalent for Mir or Wayland (for implementations not compatible with X server stuff)

Comment: In `Lubuntu 20_04` `xdotool` is preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

The following script will open a new tab in the current gnome-terminal window and optionally give that tab a title.  This works from any window, you don't have to be in a gnome-terminal window to run it.  And, if there is no gnome-terminal running, it will start one.  The only caveat is that if you changed the hotkey for opening a new tab you might have to change the line `xdotool key ctrl+T` to use your hotkey instead.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

DELAY=1
# get title we are going to set tab too, default to Terminal
title="Terminal"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    title="$1"
fi    

# get pid of running terminal server
TPID=$(ps -C gnome-terminal-server -o pid | tail -1 | sed -e's/\s//g')
if [ ${TPID} == "PID" ]; then
    # no terminal process running yet, so just start one
    gnome-terminal -t "$title" --tab
    exit 0
fi

# there is a terminal, get window id of the running terminal server
WID=$(wmctrl -lp | awk -v pid=$TPID '$3==pid{print $1;exit;}')
# get title of currently active tab
TTITLE=`xwininfo -id 0x5000006 | grep xwininfo | awk '{print $5;exit}'`
if [ "$TTITLE" == "\"Terminal\"" ]; then
    # so we don't go into an infinite loop later
    TTITLE="we had a terminal named terminal $$"
fi
# get focus on active terminal tab
xdotool windowfocus $WID
# use keyboard shortcut to open new tab
xdotool key ctrl+T

# see if we have created tab and are in terminal
NTITLE=`xwininfo -id 0x5000006 | grep xwininfo | awk '{print $5;exit}'`
waited=0
while [ "$TTITLE" == "$NTITLE" ]; do
    # sleep for 1 second before we try again
    xdotool sleep 1
    NTITLE=`xwininfo -id 0x5000006 | grep xwininfo | awk '{print $5;exit}'`
    if [ $waited == 0 ]; then
    echo "Waiting "
    waited=1
    fi
    echo -n "."
done    
if [ $waited == 1 ]; then
    echo ""
fi    

# active tab is the new one we created, wait DELAY seconds just to be sure we can type into it to set tab name
xdotool sleep $DELAY
xdotool type --clearmodifiers "termtitle $title"
xdotool key Return
# make tab the active window and raise it to top
wmctrl -i -a $WID
exit 0
```