# Why does the command "xterm xterm" create an infinite recursion?

Tags: command-line, xterm

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit). When I first found out about the command `xterm`, I tried the command `xterm xterm`, and it started infinitely opening new xterm windows.
`ctrl + C` stops it immediately and closes all windows.

But I wanted to see how far it goes and let it run as long as it can. It ate up almost all the RAM and eventually got closed (I think by the system itself).

So just out of curiosity, why/how does this happen?

Comment: Off-topic: it was closed because it probably used too much memory and got killed by the OOM (out-of-memory) killer.

Comment: This should be fixed by [version 301](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log-contents.html#xterm_301): "only set `SHELL` environment variable to programs found in `/etc/shells` (prompted by patch/report by Al Poole)". (The answers explain what's with the `SHELL` environment variable).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu - +1 - I just installed version 308 - and instead of opening recurring terminals, it opens a blank one, and a second one with bash (the second presumably being the 'shell' of the first xterm.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I (guess) this is because the first parameter you give to `xterm` is the [shell](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0010.php) to use - `xterm bash` (or `xterm /bin/bash`), `xterm python` etc.

So it runs `xterm`, tries to start `xterm` as a shell, which starts another `xterm` as that ones shell, then another, and another...

You can probably find a bit more on this by running [`man xterm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xterm.1.html)

Comment: Yes. The first `xterm` sets `$SHELL` to `xterm` and starts another `xterm` as its shell. That other `xterm` uses the command in `$SHELL` as it's shell thus starting another `xterm`, ...

Comment: This part of the answer isn't clear: "which starts another `xterm` as that ones shell". Why does that happen? Thanks @FlorianDiesch for explaining that part.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - the first `xterm` starts the second `xterm` as its shell, the second `xterm` starts the third `xterm` as its shell, the third starts the fourth as its shell... etc

Comment: I get why the first `xterm` starts the second `xterm`: it's because you typed `xterm xterm`. But why does the second `xterm` start the third `xterm`? You didn't type `xterm xterm xterm`, so it's not obvious why the third `xterm` starts. Florian's comment explains why.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: I think you should post that as a separate answer, since it gives the real explanation.

Comment: So just out of curiosity it is also possible with `gnome-terminal` ?

Comment: @Tuknutx: Interesting, I tried this: `gnome-terminal --command=gnome-terminal` . But it doesn't seem to infinitely create windows. It just opens one extra terminal. So apparently it does not work like xterm. But maybe there is a way to make it behave like that.

Comment: @LonelyKing - thats because thats gives it a command for it to run, not the shell for it to use - this might be possible if you could specify the shell just for gnome-terminal.

Comment: @Wilf Right! :)

Answer (score 16):

Short version: xterm's argument is the shell to execute by xterm; shell is set in environment var, so further calls do a `10 PRINT "xterm" 20 GOTO 10` recursion.

Long version:

1. `xterm xterm` passes `xterm` to xterm call as xterm's shell by setting `$SHELL` variable to `xterm` (1st parameter of xterm is interpreted as shell to execute)
2. then, xterm executed by your `xterm xterm` command executes the `$SHELL` - in this case, creating another xterm instance (because `$SHELL=xterm` now)
3. `$SHELL=xterm` already, so the newly created xterm executes `xterm`
4. goto 3

Further reading: [`man xterm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xterm.1.html)