# Creating a terminal from a shell script in Ubuntu

Tags: scripts

What is the name of the executable for the Ubuntu Terminal program?  I want to launch a terminal from within another terminal.  For example inside an XTerm I can write:
    xterm&
How do you do that for the Ubuntu default terminal emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the package is gnome-terminal

Here is a page with all of the switches you can use along with it

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html

Comment: Thanks - don't know why I can't accept this answer as correct immediately.  Having to wait 8 minutes is rediculous.

Answer (score 2):

Just this command will do:

```
gnome-terminal
```

Normally if you want a command to open from the terminal and separate *(so it returns to the prompt without having to close the opened program)*,  you have to use something like this:

```
gnome-terminal & disown
```

However the parent terminal seems to detect that the same command is being used so you don't need to do that and `gnome-terminal` will suffice. This also seems to happen when running `xfce4-terminal` from Xfce's terminal, `konsole` from KDE's as well (doesn't seem to work when running `xterm` from `xterm` - Running `konsole` from Gnome/Unity & Xfce's terminal works *as well*, but for Xfce's terminal in gnome terminal you need `xfce4-terminal & disown`).

For more visit [`gnome-terminal`'s manual page](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal):

```
 gnome-terminal  [-e,  --command=STRING]   [-x, --execute ]  [--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME]  [--tab-with-profile=PRO‐
       FILENAME]    [--window-with-profile-internal-id=PROFILEID]    [--tab-with-profile-internal-id=PROFILEID]    [--role=ROLE]
       [--show-menubar]   [--hide-menubar]   [--geometry=GEOMETRY]   [--disable-factory]  [-t, --title=TITLE]  [--working-direc‐
       tory=DIRNAME]  [--usage]  [-?, --help]
```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401009/command-to-open-new-terminal-window-from-the-current-terminal)

Comment: Good. But also might wanna include redirecting output of stderr