# Command to exit and then relaunch gnome-terminal that can be executed from gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, restart, execute-command

I was wondering if it is possible to sort of restart `gnome-terminal` from itself? What I mean by that is, is there a command which I can use to tell `gnome-terminal` to close and then immediately relaunch itself? I have tried running:

```
exit && gnome-terminal
```

But that doesn't work because after it has exited it can't launch itself from itself, so I was wondering if there is another command which will close it but also instruct another program to then immediately open it again?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
gnome-terminal:
  Installed: 3.18.2-1ubuntu2~wily1
  Candidate: 3.18.2-1ubuntu2~wily1
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.2-1ubuntu2~wily1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.16.2-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What about `gnome-terminal && exit`?

Comment: @ByteCommander: It needs to be closed before the new session is started.

Comment: What about `bash -c "sleep 2 && gnome-terminal" & exit` then?

Comment: That also doesn't restart `gnome-terminal-server`... Although it opens the second window after the first closes.

Comment: You could  `& disown`ing it. Some terminal programs can behave a bit weirdly when starting each other directly though, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/401012/178596)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "detach" newly spawned terminal window. Now what command does that ? `nohup` or `setsid`

`nohup gnome-terminal && exit`

`setsid gnome-terminal && exit`

Comment: Why `nohup` / `setsid`? Just `gnome-terminal && exit` ;)

Answer (score 6):

`trap` the pseudo-signal `EXIT`:

```
trap 'gnome-terminal' EXIT
```

Now everytime you run `exit` a new instance of `gnome-terminal` will be opened by shell and the existing session of shell will be terminated.

---

As @Byte Commander has pointed out, if you do `exit` (as you were doing) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to exit the shell, the above would create a `gnome-terminal` window with the same PID as the earlier one (although the shell would get a different PID), this behavior is by design. So to kill the current `gnome-terminal` process and start a new one, you can do:

```
trap 'kill $(ps -o ppid= $$) && gnome-terminal' EXIT
```

Comment: Nice, but this does only restart `gnome-terminal-server` (I'm checking it's PID in an `xterm` before and afterwards to determine this) if you close the `gnome-terminal` window. It does not do this if you run `exit` or type CTRL+D in the window.

Comment: Your edit seems to say the opposite of my comment? If the first window gets closed because the shell terminates (e.g. by running `exit`), your trap opens a new `gnome-terminal` window before the first one closes and therefore the underlying `gnome-terminal-server` instance stays the same and does not restart. It only restarts if the first window was closed by terminating the `gnome-terminal` instance, e.g. by clicking the (X) window decoration.

Comment: @ByteCommander That edit was not directed towards you..anyway good catch..check my edits..